# ¿Cómo utilizar HttpLoggingInterceptor en Volley?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit, volley

Tengo una aplicación que llama a la siguiente url `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users` la aplicación la hace por dos librerías [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) y [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley). Les dejo el código fuente https://github.com/Miguel546/androidretrofitvolley.

Si tocas el boton de **TRAER LISTA VOLLEY** la llamada la hace con Volley y si apretas el botón de **TRAE LISTA RETROFIT** lo hace con Retrofit.

[image: Aplicación Volley Retrofit]

Les dejo un gif

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BlnWMC0-eBlZWwJlOHi6tx1cSR7I4ouz/view

La llamada a retrofit la hago de la siguiente manera:

```
val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
val okBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor).build()
retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BuildConfig.UrlBase)
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
.client(okBuilder)
.build()
```

De tal manera que cada vez que hago la llamada con retrofit escribe en el logcat del Android Studio la llamada porque estoy poniendo el `client` `okbuilder` que tiene la propiedad del `HttpLoggingInterceptor` de la librería `OkHttp` el log es el siguiente:

```
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> END GET
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- 200 https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users (893ms)
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: date: Mon, 19 Jul 2021 03:26:46 GMT
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: x-powered-by: Express
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: x-ratelimit-limit: 1000
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: x-ratelimit-remaining: 999
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: x-ratelimit-reset: 1621609180
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: vary: Origin, Accept-Encoding
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: access-control-allow-credentials: true
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: cache-control: max-age=43200
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: pragma: no-cache
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: expires: -1
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: x-content-type-options: nosniff
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: etag: W/"160d-1eMSsxeJRfnVLRBmYJSbCiJZ1qQ"
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: via: 1.1 vegur
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: cf-cache-status: HIT
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: age: 11002
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=TF2Zhj99ELGtltCjRV1gvusK0Vuwm5LWFX8jjhcjUVJj6zvLmiR1bZdM2%2FRE3v82FruGRtljBSaS4hzhYkk7%2FYPwXBwwK79o79VQ98CEtRBQASqxlrHqvAI%2B9UGbZHsLi5UxcjQ%2FLz%2FyYvO6ALjFXbld6B87zisWnZDN"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: nel: {"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: server: cloudflare
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: cf-ray: 6710d9a1dbd821f1-MIA
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: alt-svc: h3-27=":443"; ma=86400, h3-28=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400, h3=":443"; ma=86400
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:   {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "id": 1,
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "name": "Leanne Graham",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "username": "Bret",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "address": {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "street": "Kulas Light",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "suite": "Apt. 556",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "city": "Gwenborough",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "zipcode": "92998-3874",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "geo": {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:         "lat": "-37.3159",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:         "lng": "81.1496"
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       }
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     },
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "website": "hildegard.org",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "company": {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     }
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:   },
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:   {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "id": 2,
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "name": "Ervin Howell",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "username": "Antonette",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "address": {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "street": "Victor Plains",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "suite": "Suite 879",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "city": "Wisokyburgh",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "zipcode": "90566-7771",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "geo": {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:         "lat": "-43.9509",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:         "lng": "-34.4618"
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       }
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     },
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "website": "anastasia.net",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "company": {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "name": "Deckow-Crist",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     }
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:   },
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:   {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "id": 3,
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "name": "Clementine Bauch",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "username": "Samantha",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "address": {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "street": "Douglas Extension",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "suite": "Suite 847",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "city": "McKenziehaven",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "zipcode": "59590-4157",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "geo": {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:         "lat": "-68.6102",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:         "lng": "-47.0653"
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       }
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     },
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "phone": "1-463-123-4447",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "website": "ramiro.info",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "company": {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "name": "Romaguera-Jacobson",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "catchPhrase": "Face to face bifurcated interface",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "bs": "e-enable strategic applications"
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     }
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:   },
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:   {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "id": 4,
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "name": "Patricia Lebsack",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "username": "Karianne",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "email": "Julianne.OConner@kory.org",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "address": {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "street": "Hoeger Mall",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "suite": "Apt. 692",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "city": "South Elvis",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "zipcode": "53919-4257",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "geo": {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:         "lat": "29.4572",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:         "lng": "-164.2990"
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       }
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     },
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "phone": "493-170-9623 x156",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "website": "kale.biz",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "company": {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "name": "Robel-Corkery",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "catchPhrase": "Multi-tiered zero tolerance productivity",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "bs": "transition cutting-edge web services"
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     }
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:   },
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:   {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "id": 5,
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "name": "Chelsey Dietrich",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "username": "Kamren",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "email": "Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "address": {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "street": "Skiles Walks",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "suite": "Suite 351",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "city": "Roscoeview",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "zipcode": "33263",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "geo": {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:         "lat": "-31.8129",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:         "lng": "62.5342"
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       }
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     },
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "phone": "(254)954-1289",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "website": "demarco.info",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "company": {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "name": "Keebler LLC",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "catchPhrase": "User-centric fault-tolerant solution",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "bs": "revolutionize end-to-end systems"
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     }
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:   },
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:   {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "id": 6,
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "name": "Mrs. Dennis Schulist",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "username": "Leopoldo_Corkery",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "email": "Karley_Dach@jasper.info",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "address": {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "street": "Norberto Crossing",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "suite": "Apt. 950",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "city": "South Christy",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "zipcode": "23505-1337",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "geo": {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:         "lat": "-71.4197",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:         "lng": "71.7478"
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       }
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     },
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "phone": "1-477-935-8478 x6430",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "website": "ola.org",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "company": {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "name": "Considine-Lockman",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "catchPhrase": "Synchronised bottom-line interface",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "bs": "e-enable innovative applications"
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     }
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:   },
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:   {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "id": 7,
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "name": "Kurtis Weissnat",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "username": "Elwyn.Skiles",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "email": "Telly.Hoeger@billy.biz",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "address": {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "street": "Rex Trail",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "suite": "Suite 280",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "city": "Howemouth",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "zipcode": "58804-1099",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "geo": {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:         "lat": "24.8918",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:         "lng": "21.8984"
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       }
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     },
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "phone": "210.067.6132",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "website": "elvis.io",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "company": {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "name": "Johns Group",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "catchPhrase": "Configurable multimedia task-force",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "bs": "generate enterprise e-tailers"
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     }
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:   },
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:   {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "id": 8,
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "name": "Nicholas Runolfsdottir V",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "username": "Maxime_Nienow",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "email": "Sherwood@rosamond.me",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "address": {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "street": "Ellsworth Summit",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "suite": "Suite 729",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "city": "Aliyaview",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "zipcode": "45169",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "geo": {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:         "lat": "-14.3990",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:         "lng": "-120.7677"
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       }
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     },
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "phone": "586.493.6943 x140",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "website": "jacynthe.com",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "company": {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "name": "Abernathy Group",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "catchPhrase": "Implemented secondary concept",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "bs": "e-enable extensible e-tailers"
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     }
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:   },
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:   {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "id": 9,
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "name": "Glenna Reichert",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "username": "Delphine",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "email": "Chaim_McDermott@dana.io",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "address": {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "street": "Dayna Park",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "suite": "Suite 449",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "city": "Bartholomebury",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "zipcode": "76495-3109",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "geo": {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:         "lat": "24.6463",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:         "lng": "-168.8889"
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       }
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     },
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "phone": "(775)976-6794 x41206",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "website": "conrad.com",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "company": {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "name": "Yost and Sons",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "catchPhrase": "Switchable contextually-based project",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "bs": "aggregate real-time technologies"
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     }
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:   },
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:   {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "id": 10,
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "name": "Clementina DuBuque",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "username": "Moriah.Stanton",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "email": "Rey.Padberg@karina.biz",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "address": {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "street": "Kattie Turnpike",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "suite": "Suite 198",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "city": "Lebsackbury",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "zipcode": "31428-2261",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "geo": {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:         "lat": "-38.2386",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:         "lng": "57.2232"
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       }
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     },
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "phone": "024-648-3804",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "website": "ambrose.net",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     "company": {
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "name": "Hoeger LLC",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "catchPhrase": "Centralized empowering task-force",
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:       "bs": "target end-to-end models"
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     }
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:   }
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: ]
18068-24707/com.luismiguel.retrofitvolley I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- END HTTP (5645-byte body)
```

Lo que deseo hacer es utilizar el `HttpLoggingInterceptor` en volley, ¿se puede?. **Mi objetivo es que con volley puedas pintar los logs se pinte el request y el response como en el log de arriba, ahora la aplicación no pinta el log solo trae la data y la pone en el RecyclerView.**

Este es el codigo que utilizo con volley

```
val url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
rvUsuarios.visibility = View.GONE
val stringRequest = StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url,
            Responseolley.Listener { response ->
                    Log.i("volley", response.toString())
                    val lista : List<UserItem> = Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), Users::class.java)
                    mainAdapter.bindData(lista)
                    rvUsuarios.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
                    rvUsuarios.hasFixedSize()
                    rvUsuarios.adapter = mainAdapter
                    rvUsuarios.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                },
                Responseolley.ErrorListener { error ->
                    Log.i("volley", "error ${error.toString()}")
                    error.stackTrace
                }
            )
MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest)
```

Comment: Hazme saber si la respuesta no te funcionó

Comment: Si me sirvío ya puse una respuesta más completa con el código por si alguien lo quiere revisar.

Comment: Esta pregunta ha sido reportada automáticamente por el sistema debido a su extensión. No necesitas tomar ninguna medida en el momento, pero lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] e intenta que tus futuras preguntas no sean tan extensas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Halle la solución utilizando esta clase https://github.com/Sottti/OkHttp-Volley-Gson/blob/096b648a9d141c6517cce897d96a73b67cc6b94f/app/src/main/java/com/sotti/okhttpvolleygson/data/OkHttp3Stack.java poniendo el `HttpLoggingInterceptor` en el método executeRequest.

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

clientBuilder.addNetworkInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);
```

Haciendo la llamada de la siguiente manera en el singleton:

```
Volley.newRequestQueue(context.applicationContext, OkHttp3Stack())
```

Y llamando al singleton desde el Main Activity.

```
MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest)
```

Aparte de eso en el singleton le quite la cache para cada vez que aprete el botón se pueda escribir el log en la clase addToRequestQueue de la clase `MySingleton.kt`.

```
requestQueue.cache.clear()
```

Les dejo el código https://github.com/Miguel546/androidretrofitvolley/tree/solucionvolley.

Saludos.

Luis Miguel Casas.

Comment: Básicamente es la misma solución.  Pero estas dos líneas están sobrando `val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this, OkHttp3Stack()); queue.add(stringRequest)` porque es lo mismo que hace el singleton. Como está ahora se realizan dos peticiones cada vez que presionas el botón (una por cada queue).

Comment: Si tienes razón esas lineas ya las quité. Ahora si se puede hacer la llamada utilizando Volley y Retrofit pintanto con `HttpLoggingInterceptor` la petición cuando apretas el botón de volley lo hace con Volley y cuando apretas el botón de Retrofit lo hace con Retrofit.

Comment: Sí pero recuerda que ni Volley ni Retrofit hacen peticiones http. Ambos son abstracciones de un cliente http de más bajo nivel. Cualquiera de los 2 botones que presiones harán la petición con okhttp. Sería interesante que agregues un botón "okHtpp" que lo haga directamente con el cliente okHttp para comparar la experiencia. Y por si no lo sabías, esa información también puedes verla en el [profiler](https://youtu.be/0n9sBgds-Hs?t=185) de android studio.

Comment: Buen dato el del profiler network esa no me la sabía.

Answer (score 1):

Si se puede pero no out of the box. Esto es porque Volley usa el cliente http nativo de android [HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting#choose-http-client) mientras que Retrofit usa el cliente [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp).

`HttpLoggingInterceptor` es un interceptor para clientes okHttp y por lo tanto para poder usarlo debes hacer que Volley funcione sobre este cliente. Para lograrlo debes crear una subclase de `BaseHttpStack` que convierta las request de volley en request de okHttp, las ejecute sobre un `OkHttpClient` y convierta las responses en responses de volley. Sería algo así

```
import com.android.volley.Header
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.toolbox.BaseHttpStack
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpResponse
import okhttp3.MediaType.Companion.toMediaTypeOrNull
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Request.Builder
import okhttp3.RequestBody.Companion.toRequestBody
import okhttp3.Response
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit


class OkHttpStack(private val okHttpClientBuilder: OkHttpClient.Builder) : BaseHttpStack() {
    override fun executeRequest(
        request: Request<*>,
        additionalHeaders: Map<String, String>
    ): HttpResponse {
        val timeout = request.timeoutMs.toLong()
        val okHttpClient = okHttpClientBuilder.apply {
            connectTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            readTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            writeTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        }.build()
        val okHttpRequest = request.toOkHttpRequest(additionalHeaders)
        val okHttpResponse = okHttpClient.newCall(okHttpRequest).execute()
        return okHttpResponse.toVolleyResponse()
    }

    private fun Response.toVolleyResponse() = HttpResponse(
        code,
        headers.map { (name, value) -> Header(name, value) },
        body?.contentLength()?.toInt() ?: 0,
        body?.byteStream()
    )

    private fun Request<*>.toOkHttpRequest(additionalHeaders: Map<String, String>): okhttp3.Request {
        val okHttpRequestBuilder = Builder().url(url)
        for ((name, value) in headers + additionalHeaders) {
            okHttpRequestBuilder.addHeader(name, value)
        }
        okHttpRequestBuilder.setConnectionParametersForRequest(this)
        return okHttpRequestBuilder.build()
    }

    private fun Builder.setConnectionParametersForRequest(request: Request<*>) {
        val requestBody = request.body?.toRequestBody(request.bodyContentType.toMediaTypeOrNull())
        val method = when (request.method) {
            Request.Method.DEPRECATED_GET_OR_POST -> if (requestBody == null) "GET" else "POST"
            Request.Method.GET -> "GET"
            Request.Method.DELETE -> "DELETE"
            Request.Method.POST -> "POST"
            Request.Method.PUT -> "PUT"
            Request.Method.HEAD -> "HEAD"
            Request.Method.OPTIONS -> "OPTIONS"
            Request.Method.TRACE -> "TRACE"
            Request.Method.PATCH -> "PATCH"
            else -> throw IllegalStateException("Unknown method type.")
        }
        method(method, requestBody)
    }

}
```

Luego cuando creas la `RequestQueue` de volley debes pasar como argumento una instancia de esta clase que acabas de crear. No muestras como implementaste `MySingleton` así que te daré un ejemplo creandola directamente

```
val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
val okClientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor)
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BuildConfig.UrlBase)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(okClientBuilder.build())
    .build()
val stringRequest = StringRequest(...)
Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext, OkHttpStack(okClientBuilder)).add(stringRequest)
```